# How can i fetch post detail page using redux from wp-rest-api

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a WordPress theme in reactjs using wp-rest-API. Till now I am able to render all the postslist page.  After this, I am trying to make post detail page using post slug and I am unable to figure out how to do that.

This is the endpoint of the wp-rest-API for post detail

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=ugiat-nulla-pariatur
```

I thought of fetching post detail endpoint something like this but I am not sure
see the code.

```
export const fetchPosts = (slug) => dispatch => {

    fetch(`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=${slug}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(posts => dispatch({
            type: FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: posts
        }))
}
```

Anyone, please help me to figure out this any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please provide output of res or posts. Are there any errors? Did you get something from the API?

Comment: After first .then(res => res.json) you need to do 
.then(res => console(JSONstringify(res))) to see what are you taking from the end point.

Comment: @vitomadio No, it gives nothing, not even any errors.

Comment: Ok just to make it clear .then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res)) , is that what you did exactly and gives no response? To take errors you will have to add . catch (err => console.log(err)) after last .then()

Comment: I did this still there is nothing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to use axios to do requests:

[Axios in Github](https://github.com/axios/axios)

I have a questions, are you using react-thunk to the async requests?

Comment: I am using redux-thunk middleware.